# React audio player - updating currentTime of an HTMLAudioElement resets to 0

Tags: reactjs, html5-audio

this is my first time posting ere, I hope I'm doing it correctly.

I'm working on an audio player component in React. The component has a progress bar, and I'm trying to update the **`currentTime`** of the audio when the user clicks or drags on the progress bar. However, whenever I try to set the **`currentTime`**, it resets to 0 instead of the desired value. I've tried different approaches, but the issue persists.

i'm using **React** **+** **TypeScript**.

Here is the code that causing me the issue :

1. The **`useRef`** that is linked to my **`<audio>`** element:

```
const audioRef = useRef<HTMLAudioElement>(null);
```

2. The **`handleMouseDown`** function that doesn't work as expected:

```
const handleMouseDown = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>): void => {
    if (audioRef.current) {
        // Pause the audio while modifying
        audioRef.current.pause();
        setIsPlaying(false);

        const width = progressRef.current!.clientWidth;
        const clickX = e.nativeEvent.offsetX;
        const duration = audioRef.current.duration;
        let newTime = (clickX / width) * duration;

        // Set the width of the progress bar 
        setProgress((newTime / duration) * 100);

        // Listen to "mousemove" and "mouseup" events to set the width of the progress bar while the mouse moves
        const handleMouseMove = (e: MouseEvent) => {
            const newX = e.clientX - progressRef.current!.getBoundingClientRect().left;
            newTime = (newX / width) * duration;
            setProgress((newTime / duration) * 100);
        };

        const handleMouseUp = () => {
            window.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
            window.removeEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);
            console.log(newTime); // Logs the correct value
            audioRef.current!.currentTime = newTime;
            audioRef.current!.play().then(() => setIsPlaying(true));
        };

        window.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
        window.addEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);
    }
};
```

The problem occurs in the **`handleMouseUp`** function when I try to set **`audioRef.current!.currentTime`**. Even though **`console.log(newTime)`** logs the correct value, the **`currentTime`** resets to 0.

the entire code can be found to my github : [**Full component code**](https://github.com/jonathanm98/react-music/blob/front/src/components/Player.tsx)

I should mention that I am a beginner in programming, so I apologize if the solution seems obvious to you, but I am completely stuck.

Comment: Have you tried `fastSeek`? (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/fastSeek). Another question, are you sure that `newTime` is in the range of the audio's length?

Comment: I don't think `fastSeek()` works on an `HTMLAudioElement`, and yes, the value of `newTime` is correct even if I replace it with, 10, I still have the same problem.

Comment: `The HTMLVideoElement and HTMLAudioElement elements both inherit this interface.` according to the doc...

Answer (score 0):

If you are serving the audio file from backend, you might want to check if the correct response headers were set. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63059735/11058010